# How to create categories in separate .h and .m files?

Tags: objective-c

In the book that I'm reading he explain how to create the categories in the main file, but I'm trying to figure out how do I do this in a separate files..

I want to create a category for Fraction class called "MathOperations", so I opened a new .h and .m called Fraction+MathOperations since I know this is the convention.

This is Fraction.h

```
#import "Fraction.h" 

@interface Fraction : NSObject

@property int numerator, denumerator;

-(void) print: (BOOL) test;
-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d;
-(void) reduce;
-(double) convertToNum;
-(id) addFrac:(id)f;
-(void) justPrint;
-(id) initWith:(int)n over:(int)f;
+(Fraction *) allocF;
+(int) count;
+(int) gCounter;

@end
```

Fraction+MathOperations.h

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@interface Fraction (MathOperations)

-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f;
-(Fraction *) substract: (Fraction *) f;
-(Fraction *) multiply: (Fraction *) f;
-(Fraction *) divide: (Fraction *) f;

@end
```

Fraction+MathOperations.m

```
    #import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction (MathOperations)

-(Fraction *)add:(Fraction *)f
{
    extern int gCounter;
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    result.numerator = numerator * f.denumerator + denumerator * f.numerator;
    result.denumerator = denumerator * f.denumerator;
    [result reduce];
    ++gCounter;
    return result;

}


-(Fraction *)substract:(Fraction *)f
{
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    result.numerator = numerator * f.denumerator - denumerator * f.numerator;
    result.denumerator = denumerator * f.denumerator;
    //[result reduce];
    return result;
}


-(Fraction *)multiply:(Fraction *)f
{
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    result.numerator = numerator * f.numerator;
    result.denumerator = denumerator * f.denumerator;
    //[result reduce];
    return result;
}

-(Fraction *)divide:(Fraction *)f
{
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    result.numerator = numerator * f.denumerator;
    result.denumerator = denumerator * f.numerator;
    //[result reduce];
    return result;
}

@end
```

Obviously I'm declaring something wrong cause im getting bunch of errors that variables are not declared..also, is it more reasonable to declare the new interface and implementation in the original Fraction class?

errors:

In the Fraction class I have some property called "numerator" and "denumerator", they seem not to be declare in the meth implementation file
tnx

Comment: The overall idea seems correct, please add to the question which exact errors for which variables are you getting?

Comment: Your code looks OK, so please post the code that includes those files and uses them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the errors? Which ones are not declared? How are they being used in the category?

Comment: In the Fraction class I have some property called "numerator" and "denumerator", they seem not to be declare in the meth implementation file @coverback

Comment: Add the code—how do you use these properties? Do you add `self.` in front?

Comment: I put the full code in the q, thanks! @coverback

Comment: Btw: The correct term for the number below the fraction line is **denominator**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is almost correct except few errors.

Find the corrected as and replace in your file

```
//
//  Fraction+MathOperations.m
//  prog3
//
//  Created by niroohayon  on 18/02/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 niroohayon . All rights reserved.
//

#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction (MathOperations)

-(Fraction *)add:(Fraction *)f
{
    //extern int gCounter;
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    result.numerator = self.numerator * f.denumerator + self.denumerator * f.numerator;
    result.denumerator = self.denumerator * f.denumerator;
    [result reduce];
   // ++gCounter;
    return result;

}


-(Fraction *)substract:(Fraction *)f
{
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    result.numerator = self.numerator * f.denumerator - self.denumerator * f.numerator;
    result.denumerator = self.denumerator * f.denumerator;
    //[result reduce];
    return result;
}


-(Fraction *)multiply:(Fraction *)f
{
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    result.numerator = self.numerator * f.numerator;
    result.denumerator = self.denumerator * f.denumerator;
    //[result reduce];
    return result;
}

-(Fraction *)divide:(Fraction *)f
{
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    result.numerator = self.numerator * f.denumerator;
    result.denumerator = self.denumerator * f.numerator;
    //[result reduce];
    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: @AKV this did solve the errors, but now I have this in the Fraction+MathOperations.h http://d.pr/i/F11T

Comment: @Nir This is **not** the answer, so undo it to solve the new issues you are facing.

Comment: the error says, compiler is not getting what is Fraction!!! Check for availability of this file and no typo and spelling mistake.

Comment: @AKV Your approach is wrong; you don't need (or want) to include a category header file from within the class header file like this.  Also you aren't always able to, given most categories extend Apple-provided classes.  The actual issue he saw when using your approach is that Fraction isn't actually defined when the category header file is included.

Comment: @trojanfoe : I didn't do anything, i just use apple's template to create a category and I advised him to do that.

Comment: @AKV No your answer tells him to include the category header file inside the header file of the class being categorised, which has not yet been defined.  This is plain wrong, and as Nir has discovered just leads to more errors.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Oh shitttt, What i did was a sheer blunder mistake..... updating my answer. Sorry I failed to understand your comment :(

Comment: @Nir: Sorry i did a mistake, kindly rollback to your original code.

Comment: @AKV Your profile looks very self-deprecating; it almost looks like it's been hacked: "7+ Years of IT experience, **FOR NO USE**. Currently working as Tech Lead, TechMahindra, **FOR MONEY**. Mainly Mac application developer, **BUT ALL CRASHES**. Started career as Professor(C, C++, VB, Java, Swing, NetBeans, Oracle, PLSQL) then moved to development using Visual Basic and Oracle, **DONT KNOW WHY**."

Comment: @trojanfoe: Its not hacked, I only updated in anger when i was getting bulk downvotes.

Comment: Not Yet..i'm missing something here @AKV

Comment: @AKV same thing...I dont get what trojanfoe said about the `self`, is would help if I knew what the main should look like

Comment: @Nir: quickly mail me your proj. I have 30min time :)

Comment: This solution (use `self.` to access the properties) has already been given by coverback 1 hour ago.

Comment: @MartinR: yes you are right, and he used some `extern variables`, that was also creating error, i commented those.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `self.` prefix, like `self.numerator` for each of the main class's property. Category doesn't have any "internal" access to the properties, it behaves like any external user.

Comment: +1 I agree; this is certainly *the* error.  Because he's using the "declare a property without declaring an instance variable" shortcut, he needs to refer to those properties like that from inside the `Fraction` implementation as well.  Those shortcuts rarely save time IMHO.

Comment: Thanks! is that common to create categories like this in separate files, of I should do this in the original fraction files? @trojanfoe

Comment: @trojanfoe see that i have created a new object in those methodes and im using it as `result.numerator` so how do I change this to `self`?

Comment: @trojanfoe would be nice if you could show me a simple short exmple of the main

Comment: @Nir: For example `result.numerator = self.numerator * f.numerator;` and `result.denumerator = self.denumerator * f.denumerator;` in the multiply function.

Answer (score 1):

I think simply changing this:

```
#import "Fraction.h"
```

to this:

```
#import "Fraction+MathOperations.h"
```

in `Fraction+MathOperations.m` will do the trick.

Comment: This could account for some method definition problems, but not for main classes properties.

Comment: @coverback I think perhaps there is more than one simple error going on here.